# Cin doesn't wait for my input even if I reset it with cin.sync() and cin.clear()

Tags: c++, reset, cin

Today i started working on a quite big project and found this problem I've never found. I always used to reset the cin stream with the usage in sequence of sync() and clear(). But after i changed my compiler (a month ago i switched from standalone minGW to minGW through msys2) to have filesystem included in the std library, it seems this combination doesn't work anymore. Now I'm asking 2 different questions:

1. Does anyone knows why exactly? (I'm using gcc 11.2.0, just checked on my CMD)
2. How can I solve this problem?

Here's the example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    string s;
    cout << "insert a number" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    cin.sync();
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Now insert a string" << endl;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << "This is your number: " << number << endl;
    cout << "This is your string: " << s << endl;
}
```

And here's the terminal:

```
insert a number
8
Now insert a string
This is your number: 8
This is your string:
```

Obviously as you can see it doesn't wait for my input and i think it gets my enter as a char for the string. That's why it prints what seems to be nothing (it's simply '\n')

Comment: You seem to be on the right track, but `sync` does nothing here. You need to [`ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) everything up to `'\n'`

Comment: Side note: Please don't pollute global namespace. EPA will not be happy.